# Is there any functional reason for including the version number in the name of a JAR file?

Tags: java, jar, conventions

In Java, I often see JAR files named with the version number of the software (`jsoup-1.11.2.jar`), while others are not (`freemarker.jar`).

Is this just a best practice/convention, or is there some functional reason for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: no, this is purely a convention.

Obviously, tooling that checks versions can do that easily when version numbers are hard-coded like this. But there is no generic (like jvm based) tool relying on it.

And beyond that - sometimes this scheme is even counter productive. In our self grown build setup we have to always remember to update the build scripts after replacing JAR files - because a new version changes the file name (because version part of the file name).

Comment: The problem with manual updating the version can be easily avoided by using a tool like Gradle to automatically update the version number.

Comment: Tell that our managers. They consider our home grown build system to be good enough for the next two years.

Answer (score 0):

Having the version in the name of the file allows you to quickly determine which of the `n` files you have is the latest. Also if you have no way of determining what the version is from within the program it can be helpful.